# React Route element Showing all in one page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to React and im trying build a live chat website , but i got stuck in the section of login and registration , im just trying to navigate between these 2 pages i will put my code under , if i did something wrong don't hesitate please :

**App.js :**
`

```
import './App.css';
import React ,{Component} from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes, Link 
} from "react-router-dom";
import LoginPage from './componenets/login/LoginPage';
import Register from './componenets/Register/Register';

class App extends Component {
render() {
   return (
      <Router>
      <div className='App-header'>
        <Typography variant="h1" component="h2">
                Live Chat
        </Typography>
        <div className='group_btn'>
            <div className='btn'>
            <Link to='/logn'>
            <Button className='btn_s' variant="contained" color='success' size="large">
                Login 
              </Button>
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className='btnc'>
            <Link to='/reg'>
            <Button className='btn_s'  variant="contained" color='success' size="large">
                Register 
              </Button>
              </Link>
            </div>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/logn' exact element={<LoginPage/>}/>
              <Route path='/reg' exact element={<Register/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
      </Router>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

`**LoginPage.js :**`

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react'
import './LoginPage.css'
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

class Login_Page extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <div className='lgn'>
      <div className='title'>
        <Typography variant="h1" component="h2">
              Live Chat
        </Typography>
      </div> 
      <div className='lgn_inputs'>
          <Box
          component="form"
          sx={{
            '& > :not(style)': { m: 1, width: '45ch' },
          }}
          noValidate
          autoComplete="off"
          >
          <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Username" variant="outlined" />
          <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Email" variant="outlined" />
          <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Password" variant="outlined" />
          </Box>
      </div>
      <div className='btn'>
      <Button className='btn_s' href='#' onClick={ () => alert('You are Logged in') } variant="contained" color='success' size="large">
          Login 
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
   );
  }
  }
  
export default Login_Page;
```

`

i've tried so many things like : Switch but it gives me blank page , i did use useNavigate and i got the same result like the code above.

Comment: This isn't causing the issue, but do not use underscores in React component names. class Login_Page -> class LoginPage.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<Route></Route>
```

instead of

```
<Route />
```

Let me know if that works

Comment: yeah i already tried it :(

Comment: Change Component class name to LoginPage and the export default to LoginPage - let me know if that works

Comment: unfortunaly nothing happend btw this what i was talkin about ,https://ibb.co/1L3wm2b ,https://ibb.co/NTNNkcC

Comment: So you want to not have duplicates when you change pages?

Comment: yes excatly each page by itself

Comment: Comment all the html/jsx in the app.js ( Everything between Router and Routes). Then for the first route set the path='/'

Comment: that cannot work. its semantically the same.

Comment: very unlikely to fix the problem

Comment: Literally how my project now is setup and it works

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Router that wraps the entire App component...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use the new `createBrowserRouter`?

```js
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
const loginRegRouter = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/logn",
    element: <LoginPage/>,
  },
  {
    path: "/reg",
    element: <Register/>,
  },
]);
```

then you can change your code like:
delete this:

```js
<Routes>
 <Route path='/logn' exact element={<LoginPage/>}/>
 <Route path='/reg' exact element={<Register/>}/>
</Routes>
```

and add this:

```js
<RouterProvider router={loginRegRouter} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is you can add all the login button & Register button on and HomePage Component Which mean you can create new HomePage Component which keep the code separate from the routing code and also feasible and good pratic.

HomePage.js

```
import { Typography, Button, Link, Switch } from "@mui/material";

export const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App-header">
      <Typography variant="h1" component="h2">
        Live Chat
      </Typography>
      <div className="group_btn">
        <div className="btn">
          <Button
            className="btn_s"
            variant="contained"
            color="success"
            size="large"
            href="/login"
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </div>
        <div className="btnc">
          <Button
            className="btn_s"
            variant="contained"
            color="success"
            size="large"
            href="/reg"
          >
            Register
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

LoginPage.js

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Input, InputLabel, Link } from "@mui/material";

export const LoginPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="lgn">
      <div className="title">Login</div>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel>Email</InputLabel>
        <Input />
        <InputLabel>Password</InputLabel>
        <Input />
      </FormControl>
      <div className="btn">
        <button>login</button>
        <Link href="/">Go Back</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Register.js

```
import {
  FormControl,
  Box,
  FormGroup,
  Input,
  InputLabel,
  Link,
  Button,
} from "@mui/material";

export const Register = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <div>Register</div>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel>UserName</InputLabel>
        <Input />
        <InputLabel>Email</InputLabel>
        <Input />
        <InputLabel>Password</InputLabel>
      </FormControl>
      <Box>
        <Button>Register</Button>
        <Link href="/">Go Back</Link>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "./App.css";
import { Typography, Button, Link } from "@mui/material";
// import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { LoginPage } from "./LoginPage";
import { Register } from "./Register";
import { HomePage } from "./HomePage";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App-header">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<LoginPage />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/reg" element={<Register />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please ignore the styling, just want to explain you the routing.